# Create lookup to name field document set

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I want to create a lookup column that references the 'Name' field of a document set.
I can only choose document titles but I want to reference the document set name that the user gives to it. Is there an option to achive

Comment: As far as I know when you create a lookup column (in background relationship) with another Table, By default you have 3 metadata of that table (record) Primary column (i.e in this case Title), Guid (Id of a record), Table type(schema name of Table).
So if for table document set your primary column is Title it will refer or show only title.
let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and I have managed to get the name column referenced. It was just between the options to choose from but somehow the lookup only showed old metadata. I deleted the library and lookup column and tried again and this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test and knowledge, there is no option to use document set name as reference in the lookup column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have managed to get the document set name referenced. It was just between the options to choose from but somehow the lookup only showed old metadata. I deleted the library and lookup column and tried again and this worked.